# Какими методами можно вывести и как правильно выводить на страницу данные полученные от сервера в результате обработки Ajax запроса?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, extjs

Я постараюсь описать как можно подробнее суть моей проблемы, что я пытаюсь сделать и что я уже пробовал сделать, итак..

Имеется каталог товаров и мне нужно, что бы по нажатию на определённый элемент списка выводились карточки товаров относящиеся к тематике выбранного элемента списка.

[image: Описание]
.

Как реализовать вывод карточек товаров я знаю. И без Ajax это выглядело бы так:

Была бы ссылка передающая название раздела методом "GET".

`<a href = "?pc">Комплектующие ПК</a>`

Код php который выводит карточки товара в нужном месте:

```
if (isset(($_GET['pc']))) {

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tableName`";
    $result = $pdo->query($query);

    foreach ($result as $array) {
        $name = $array['name']; //наименование товара
        $price = $array['price']; //цена товара

        include 'card.php';  //подключение шаблона "карточки товара"
    }
}
```

И сам шаблон карточки товара "card.php":

```
<div class = "card">
  <div class = "card-header fl">
      <p class = "product-name fl-al-c"> <?php echo $name; ?> </p> <!-- Наименование -->
  </div>

  <div class = "card-content fl">
      <img src = "images/img.png" alt = "#">
  </div>

  <div class = "card-footer fl-al-c">
      <p class = "price"> <?php echo $price; ?> </p> <!-- Цена товара -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Но теперь мне необходимо сделать тоже самое, но с помощью Ajax который я начал изучать совсем недавно.

Я построил следующий Ajax запрос:

```
Sel.on('click', function(){

Ext.Ajax.request({

    url: 'php/handler.php',
    method: 'POST',
    params: { 
        category: 'pc'
    },

    success: function (response) {
        var objAjax = Ext.decode(response.responseText); //запись полученных данных в objAjax
        var elementsInObjAjax = (Object.keys(objAjax).length); //количество элементов в objAjax

        console.log("Ajax request: success // (sendAjaxRequest)");
        console.log(objAjax);

        for (var i = 0; i < elementsInObjAjax; i++) {
            name = objAjax[i]['name'];  //наименование
            price = objAjax[i]['price'];    //цена

            $('#products').load('php/card.php');
        }
    },

    failure: function () {
        console.log("Ajax request: failure // (sendAjaxRequest)");
    }

  });

});
```

И написал вот такой код обработчика:

```
if ((isset($_POST['category'])) && (!empty($_POST['category']))) {

    $tableName = $_POST['category'];

    $query = "SELECT * FROM `$tableName`";
    $result = $pdo->query($query);

    $data = array();

    foreach ($result as $array) {
        array_push($data, $array);
    }

    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

Как видно из консоли, все данные были получены.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в результате, выводиться только одна карточка. Код в теле цикла for повторяется столько раз, сколько элементов в массиве полученном от сервера. Но вот следующий фрагмент:

```
$('#products').load('php/card.php');
```

Похоже работает только один раз или просто заменяет предыдущие данные в карте на новые.

Я довольно долго рылся в интернете в поисках ответа на тему обработки ответа и вставки на страницу, но так ничего и не нашёл. Видимо плохо искал.

Comment: Jquery.load просто подгружает данные из урла. У вас уже есть все данные в джсоне, на этом взаимодействие с сервером прекращается и данные из джсона выводятся в html.

Comment: Не очень кстати ясно зачем вы используете jquery и extjs вместе.

Comment: для добавления кода в конец контейнера $("").append("<div></div>") и в начало $("").preppend("<div></div>")

Answer (score 0):

[Документация](http://api.jquery.com/load/) $.load говорит, что после запроса весь контейнер заменяется html-ответом с сервера.

Один из способов - прокинуть коллбэк в сам $.load, который по завершению дополняет контейнер, и соответственно очищать контейнер при первом вызове во избежании перезаполнения "старыми" данными.

```js
const $products = $('#products')

function concatProducts (newHtml) {
  let oldHtml = $products.html()
  $products.html(oldHtml + newHtml)
}

// до главного вызова (цикла)
$products.html('')

// далее получаем html и конкатенируем
$products.load('php/card.php', concatProducts)
```

А так - способов много - от любого [ajax-метода](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp) jQuery/библиотек типа [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) до классического [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)/[XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), зависит уже от задач и потребностей.

В Вашем случае, если с сервера приходит html - нужно его просто вставить в контейнер, два варианта - либо конкатенировать (если запросов на каждую карточку несколько), либо обновлять html-код контейнера (если запрос один на пачку карточек).

В случае с json-ответом достаточно создать html-шаблон карточки и рисовать, например используя [underscore](https://underscorejs.org/#template)/php-шаблоны или обычный html.

Answer (score 0):

Для вывода карточки товара можно создать следующую функцию:

```
function renderCARD(t) {

    var Card = {

        tag: 'div',
        cls: 'card fadeIn',
        id: id,

        children: [{

            tag: 'div',
            cls: 'card-header fl pc-c',

                children: [{
                    tag: 'p',
                    cls: 'product-name fl-al-c',
                    html: name
                }]
            },{

            tag: 'div',
            cls: 'card-content fl',

                children: [{
                    tag: 'img src = "images/products/computer-parts/no-image.png" alt = "#"',
                }]
            },{

            tag: 'div',
            cls: 'card-footer fl-al-c',

                children: [{
                    tag: 'p',
                    cls: 'price',
                    html: price
            }]
        }]
    };

    Ext.core.DomHelper.append(t, Card);
}
```

- В объект Card записывается html разметка карточки товара, он является
  "шаблоном".
- Используя класс Ext.core.DomHelper, можно вывести шаблон    в
  записанное в переменную "t" место.

Далее нужно вызвать функцию renderCARD(t) в цикле:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elementsInObjAjax; i++) {
       name = objAjax[i]['name'];
       price = objAjax[i]['price'];
       id = objAjax[i]['id'];

       renderCARD(products);
}
```